# Timescale not finding pg_config on AMI

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ami, timescaledb

I created a machine in AWS Cloud9 and I want to install timescale on that instance.  I have previously installed and setup postgres 9.6 using yum.

OS version is:

> Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03

.

When I run '`which pg_config`', it is found here:

> /usr/bin/pg_config

Looking at the install instructions on the timescale website, I came up with this:

> sudo yum install -y
>   https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
>
> wget
>   https://timescalereleases.blob.core.windows.net/rpm/timescaledb-0.9.2-postgresql-9.6-0.x86_64.rpm
>
> sudo yum install timescaledb-0.9.2-postgresql-9.6-0.x86_64.rpm

after the last command I get the following error:

> Running transaction   Installing :
>   timescaledb-0.9.2-0.el7.centos.x86_64
>   1/1  ERROR: Could not find pg_config, expected it at
>   /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config. Please fix and try again.
>
> warning: %post(timescaledb-0.9.2-0.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet
>   failed, exit status 1 Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm
>   package timescaledb-0.9.2-0.el7.centos.x86_64

Comment: Looks like the RPM expects PostgreSQL to be installed with the PGDG RPMs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more details on how you installed PostgreSQL on CentOS? I suspect this may have something to do with a mismatch between your pg_config installation and your PostgreSQL 9.6 installation, similar to the user in [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972378/apt-installed-postgres-version-does-not-match-pg-config-version).

I'd recommend uninstalling your current `postgresql-devel` and explicitly installing it for 9.6:

```
yum install postgresql96-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the AMI is setup a bit differently than a normal CentOS install so PostgreSQL is installed in a different place than our installer expected. I've gone ahead and updated the RPMs to use a more robust method of finding the correct place to put the files. If you could re-download the latest RPM and confirm that it works that'd be great.

Comment: I tried this again and it didn't work.  I downloaded the PGDG again for my installation, re-ran that with sudo yum reinstall, that worked.  Then downloaded the rpm, got the same error: Running transaction
  Installing : timescaledb-0.9.2-0.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                     1/1 
ERROR: Could not find pg_config, expected it at /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config. Please fix and try again.

And here is how I install postgres: sudo yum install postgresql96-server postgresql96-contrib

Comment: I did not go back and update older versions of TimescaleDB, so you'll need to use the image for 0.10.1 in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've met exactly the same problem.
I solve this by manually linking them together.

sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_config /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config